# Factory Girl Associations with Spork Discrepancy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot, spork

I'm trying to use Factory Girl for RSpec with Spork. Whenever I run my tests without spork, everything passes, but when I run it with Spork, all the tests that try to create an instance of a factory that depends on another factory, fail. For example:

```
3) Invitation has a correctly formed body
   Failure/Error: request = FactoryGirl.create(:request, ....)
   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `user=' for #<Request:0x007f86b6a87890>
```

And my `factories.rb` code looks roughly like this

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:first_name) { |n| "first_name#{n}" }
    sequence(:last_name) { |n| "last_name#{n}" }
  end

  factory :request do
    association :user, :factory => :user, :is_walker => false
  end
end
```

My code only seems to break when there is an association, and then it tries to call the setter on the `:user`. Why might this be happening?

Here are the versions I'm using

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
gem 'spork', '0.9.0.rc5'
gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
```

Comment: Can't help you with your question, but +1 because the question title sounds really funny out of context.

Answer (score 6):

Do you have `require 'factory_girl_rails` in your `Spork.each_run` block?

I have use the following in my gemfile:

```
  gem "factory_girl_rails", :require => false
```

in spec_helper.rb:

```
Spork.each_run do

  require 'factory_girl_rails'
  FactoryGirl.factories.clear
  FactoryGirl.reload

end
```

Not sure if it will help but it's worth a shot.

Comment: `FactoryGirl.factories.clear` and `FactoryGirl.reload` are not necessary (at least with the newest factory_girl).

Answer (score 0):

Is it really any tests that have an association or any tests that try to create a :request factory?  I've never used spork, but the fact it works without it makes me wonder if spork/factory_girl are fighting over "Request"... worth looking into.